# concatenar elementos de un arreglo usando un foreach

Tags: php

Quiero concatenar los elementos dentro de un string algo asi

```
             $operad='';
              foreach($planificacion as $plan){
                $operad+= ($plan->operador);
            }
```

para al final tenerlo todo en un string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hazlo asi:

```
$operad='';
foreach($planificacion as $plan){
    $operad .= $plan->operador;
}
```

Los elementos de concatenación de que dispones en PHP los encontraras en el manual de PHP:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php

Comment: dale amigo gracias, otra pregunta actualmente esto me trae un string algo así 
[494,528,2,497,2,2,2,2][2,494,495,498,496,572,528], como podría quitarle esos corchetes??

Comment: Eso son arrays seguramente. ¿Como te aparecen?  Estoy fuera de contexto